# Java Protected Variables can be accessed inside same package without inheritance how?

Tags: java, inheritance

Please see below program and comments:

Please tell me how another class can access protected member without inheritance? I have compiled and run this program at my end.

```
class Sample3
{
   final protected String Var1 = "Sample 3 Final Varaible";
   final private String Var2 = "Sample 3 Final Varaible";
}//class Sample3

class Sample4
{
 public static void main(String args[])
 {
    Sample3 s3=new Sample3();
    //System.out.println(s3.Var2);// Line 12 : this is not accessible as the Private member is being accessed 
    System.out.println(s3.Var1);//Line 13 : this access the protected member but i have not used inheritance between 2 classes Sample3 and Sample4
 }//end of main
}/class Sample4
```

Var1 is the Class protected member, Var2 is the class private member.

I am creating the Object of the Sample3 inside Sample4. Line 12 is clearly an error but how it can compile line 13?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the correct behaviour.  `protected` allows the member to be seen by all classes in the same package, not just subclasses.  See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html.

Answer (score 2):

Remember protected as this way- default+inheritance. `Protected` access modifier allows access in same package + subclass in other packages.